# Android / Java / Kotlin : Merge 2 Bitmaps in one Canvas

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm trying to create a kotlin function responsible to take 2 Bitmaps and return one corresponding to the two merge images.

The first one is a default white rounded marker (emptyMarkerBitmap) with a fix width and height.
The second one is an random image that I would like to minimize to fill the first image in overlay.

```
private fun createBitmapOverlay(emptyMarkerBitmap: Bitmap, categoryIconBitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {

      val cs: Bitmap

      val width: Int = emptyMarkerBitmap.width
      val height: Int = emptyMarkerBitmap.height

      cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

      val comboImage = Canvas(cs)

      comboImage.drawBitmap(emptyMarkerBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
      comboImage.drawBitmap(categoryIconBitmap, emptyMarkerBitmap.width.toFloat(), 0f, null)

     return cs

}
```

For the moment, I always get displayed the first image which is the white marker. My second image is never displayed. Where is the issue ?

Comment: you are drawing the second image outside your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 fun Bitmap.with(bmp: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        // Create new bitmap based on the size and config of the old
        val newBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)

        // Instantiate a canvas and prepare it to paint to the new bitmap
        val canvas = Canvas(newBitmap)

        // Draw the old bitmap onto of the new white one
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0f, 0f, null)

        return newBitmap
  }

emptyMarkerBitmap.with(categoryIconBitmap)
```

Comment: This is better but not enough. The 2 images needs to be rescaled to fit the first image area.

Comment: so you should use your first image width and height as Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)

Comment: Yes, but the `bmp` variable needs to be scaled also to fit the newBitmap area. How can I handle that ?

Comment: ```
fun Bitmap.resize(width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap {
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this, width, height, false)
}
```